# How to use Watir to automate apps written in node-webkit?

Tags: watir, node-webkit

I've been using Watir to automate Chrome browser based UI testing (loading web pages, performing actions on HTML elements etc) and it's been a great success.

We are starting some new projects that use node-webkit (https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit), a Chromium and node.js based app runtime. I haven't figured out how to use Waitr to automate it.

Does anyone know how to do it? If not, is there any other tool for this purpose?

Thanks for the help.